# How can I export the schema of my sql server 2008 to another computer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have created a database on Sql Server 2008 and I want to export the schema (I don't need the data) to another computer?

Comment: [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can generate script to script out your schema to a sql file and then execute that in another server, right click on the database in management studio, select Task-> Generate Scripts